# Apple/Gmail ID with Company email

Tags: gmail, testflight, portal, apple-id

While giving accesses to internal teams on Apple and Google portals, I normally send an invite to organisations emails ID.

This means the users create a gmail or Apple ID by using company email.

What happens if these users leave the organisation? I assume the Apple n Gmail id will continue to exist with the company email?

Why not send the invite to their personal gmail n Apple ID itself then?